# C# - Allowing ampersands (&) to be entered in Textboxes and stored

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, groupbox, ampersand

I can find multiple solutions all involving labels, but I can't seem to find any solutions or suggestions for allowing ampersands to be used via text boxes?

I have a WinForm that users have to configure on first load, and it's not uncommon for them to enter '&' into one of the fields. Once saved, this value is then used as a `groupBox` title, but the '&' is stripped out. It's untidy asking them to enter the ampersand twice (&&) for it to display correctly.

[image]
[image]

Is it possible for a single '&' to be added into a text filed, then used without it being removed?

**Edit**: To clarify, the textbox value is used as the Text value for a **groupbox** so `UseMnemonic` is not an option here.

Comment: You could detect and replace 1 with 2 :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could escape it by:

```
_schoolGroupBox.Text = _federationNameTextBox.Text.Replace("&", "&&");
```

Comment: Perfect! Tested and works just as I want it to! Users can put in one '&', and a single '&' gets displayed in the title. Plus if they choose to change it at a later data, again only one '&' is displayed in the text box! Thanks alot! :)